# Try to replace the nan values by pandas , but Error: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, deep-learning, kaggle

It is a simple project in Kaggle, just imitating one blog, but failed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htJcY.png)

*train_inf['Age']=train_inf.fillna(train_inf['Age'].median())
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key*

**just this code**

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, need specify column `Age` for replace missing values:

```
train_inf['Age']=train_inf['Age'].fillna(train_inf['Age'].median())
```